# Display Linked List: Null Pointer Exception Error

Tags: java, linked-list, decision-tree

I keep getting the null exception error when trying to output my linked list.

I do not get that error when I only print the condition name and the empty can test value !!!? not sure the reason why?

But when I try to iterate throughout my entire linked list to print it out, I get the Null Exception error

```
public class ItemLinkedList {

    private ItemInfoNode head;
    private ItemInfoNode tail;
    private int size = 0;

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void addBack(ItemInfo info) {
        size++;
        if (head == null) {
            head = new ItemInfoNode(info, null, null);
            tail = head;
        } else {
            ItemInfoNode node = new ItemInfoNode(info, null, tail);
            this.tail.next = node;
            this.tail = node;
        }
    }

    public ItemInfo removeFront() {
        ItemInfo result = null;
        if (head != null) {
            size--;
            result = head.info;
            if (head.next != null) {
                head.next.prev = null;
                head = head.next;
            } else {
                head = null;
                tail = null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ItemLinkedList list = new ItemLinkedList();

        list.addBack( new ItemInfo("Bicipital Tendonitis", 1, 0, 1, 1) );
        list.addBack( new ItemInfo("Coracoid Impingement", 0, 1, 1, 1) );
        list.addBack( new ItemInfo("Supraspinatus Impingement", 1, 0, 0, 1) );
        list.addBack( new ItemInfo("Bicipital Tendonitis", 1, 0, 1, 1) );
        list.addBack( new ItemInfo("Glenohumeral Dislcation", 0, 0, 1, 1) );
        list.addBack( new ItemInfo("Clavicular Fracture", 1, 0, 1, 0) );
        list.addBack( new ItemInfo("Labral Tear", 1, 1, 0, 0) );     
        list.addBack( new ItemInfo("SubAcromial Bursitis", 1, 0, 0, 0) );


         while (list.getSize() > 0){

            System.out.println( "Condition Name " + list.removeFront().getCondName() );
            System.out.println( "\t Empy Can Test: " + list.removeFront().getEmptyCanTest() );
            System.out.println( "\t Speed's Test: " + list.removeFront().getSpeedsTest() );
            System.out.println( "\t Apprehension Test: " + list.removeFront().getApprehensionTest() );
            System.out.println( "\t Pain Provocation Test: " + list.removeFront().getpainProvocationTest() );
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Comment: please post your exception stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop's condition checks that there's at least one element in the list, but then you try to remove 5 elements from the list.

You should call `removeFront` only once in each iteration :

```
     while (list.getSize() > 0){
        ItemInfo item = list.removeFront();
        System.out.println( "Condition Name " + item.getCondName() );
        System.out.println( "\t Empy Can Test: " + item.getEmptyCanTest() );
        System.out.println( "\t Speed's Test: " + item.getSpeedsTest() );
        System.out.println( "\t Apprehension Test: " + item.getApprehensionTest() );
        System.out.println( "\t Pain Provocation Test: " + item.getpainProvocationTest() );
        System.out.println();
    }
```